# method closes program for no reason

Tags: java, string, swing

In my university project, I need to display the names of the players, and their score.
I want it to look like this :

```
Name1 . . . . . . . . 1200
Another Name . . . . . . 3
A Very Very Long name  . 2
```

In order to know the number of dots, I need to know the length of the string on the screen, so all the strings will have the same length.
`text.length` will not help because letters like `l` takes less space than `T` for example.

After looking on the internet for a while, I have found someone who said that, in order to get the length of the string on the screen, I can do this:

```
private int stringViewLength(String text) {
    AffineTransform affinetransform = new AffineTransform();     
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(affinetransform, true, true);     
    Font font = new Font(FONT, Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE);

    int textWidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(text, frc).getWidth()); // This line causes problems
    int textHeight = (int)(font.getStringBounds(text, frc).getHeight()); // Not in use

    return textWidth;
}
```

The problem is that the line:

```
int textWidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(text, frc).getWidth()); // This line causes problems
```

for some reason, will not allow the program to run. It does not throw any exception, nor returns unexpected values, nor shuts down the program.
After debugging, I saw that as long as this line was executed, 
at the end of the `main` function, for some reason, the method `exit()` in `Thread` is called, but when I comment this line (and replace the `return` statement for a const number), the line is displayed on the screen.

What would cause this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I can't speak for all, but I know that I would benefit *greatly* by your creating and posting a valid [mcve] program with your question, a small program, small enough to be allowed to be posted as code-formatted text in the question, one that compiles, runs, and that demonstrates the problem for us and nothing more.

Comment: Note that if you're displaying your text in a Swing GUI text component, such as a JTextArea, then why not simply make the Font `Font.MONOSPACED`, and this way the String length *may* be well used.

Comment: Option 2: if this is a Swing GUI and you're trying to display tabular data, use a JTable, a component specifically built for the display and manipulation of tabular data.

Comment: oh, didn't know I can do this, thanks!

Comment: Did you try and surround the problematic line with a try block, and see if any exception is caught? It's possible there actually was an exception that was handled somewhere else (where exit() is called).

Comment: @BrunoRyckaert: I was actively wondering if there's an empty catch block in the code somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-engineering the solution. You can not easily align any text in a non- monospaced font. Simply use Courier and get on with the purpose of your lesson in building an app. Sometimes the best lesson is to use the simplest solution.